# Google cloud storage - How to specify allowed file formats as part of signed URL

Tags: google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

Google cloud storage - How to specify allowed file formats as part of signed URL validation

I want to allow only zip files to be uploaded to GCS by the user .How do I restrict the user ? User will have only signed URL ,which directly interacts with GCP .

Is there any attribute which can be set as part of generating signed URL ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot specify the file format. You can only specify the Content-Type. I could rename a PNG to ZIP and the upload would complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `-c <content_type>` as zip while creating the signed URL.

Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl)